# Постфиксный декремент

Tags: c#

большая просьба помочь разобраться со следующим примером:

```
int a = -1;
a = a-- *a;
```

Почему консоль выводит ответ "2"?

Comment: Просто никогда не пишите такой код и всё.

Comment: [курсы какие-то?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/988254/178576)

Answer (score 5):

**В реальном коде крайне не рекомендуется в одном и том же выражении повторно использовать переменную, над которой выполняется операция инкремента или декремента.**

## Объяснение

Постфиксная операция работает так:

- Запоминаем значение операнда
- Изменяем операнд
- Подставляем в выражение запомненное значение

Расставим скобки согласно приоритету операторов и начнем вычислять:

```
a = (a--) * a  // a: -1
a = -1 * a     // a: -2
a = -1 * -2    // a: -2
a = 2          // a: -2 (все еще, потому что присвоение не отработало)
```

В итоге `a` стало равно 2.

## Почему это плохо?

А чтобы понимать, почему написание такого кода сравнимо с использованием `goto` (а по-моему, даже хуже), рассмотрим такой пример:

```
a = a * (a--)  // a: -1
```

Думаете, операция в скобках выполнится первой? Нет, операции в C# выполняются слева направо, приоритеты и скобки только устанавливают ассоциативность. Так что сначала в выражение подставится результат "вычисления" первого операнда. А в C++, если я правильно помню, это вообще *undefined behavior*.

```
a = -1 * (a--) // a: -1
a = -1 * -1    // a: -2
a = 1          // a: -2
```

После того, как присвоение отработает, в `a` будет 1.

Для тренировки предлагаю решить вручную классическую задачу

```
int i = 5;
i = ++i + ++i;
```

Должно получиться 13.

## А когда использование этих операций допустимо?

Когда вы не используете эту переменную в том же выражении, вы не будете думать, как второе ее вхождение подставится в это выражение. Пример:

```
while (--i > 0) ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Постфиксный декремент возвращает значение переменной, данной на вход, а уже потом производит вычитание единицы из неё.
Ход действий в данном случае:
1) a = -1;
2) a = a-- * a;
3) a = -1 * a;
4) Выполняется декремент, a = -2;
5) a = -1 * -2;
6) a = 2;

Comment: То есть, сперва все равно будет декремент, а потом умножение?

Comment: @Настя, именно.

Comment: @AlexKrass, ну так в первом случае и получается: сначала декремент, а уже потом умножение.

Comment: @user263096 бывает, сам запутался, видимо пора возвращаться к основам))